# Proof that a complex function is continuous at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Given the function
  $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ by
  $f(z)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{xy(x+iy)}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } z\neq 0\\
  0 & \text{if } z=0
  \end{cases}$ with $z=x+iy$.

How do I proof that $f$ is continuous in $z=0$?

I've tried using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ -definition, giving me to proof $|x+iy|<\delta \Rightarrow \left|\frac{xy(x+iy)}{x^2+y^2}\right|<\epsilon$.

I've tried rewriting the right component, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I just don't 'see' it.
Can someone give me a hint to the solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left|\frac{xy(x+iy)}{x^2+y^2}\right| = |z| \frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{1}{2}|z|
$$
because $|xy| \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: So that would give me a solution, by using $\epsilon=\frac12\delta$. However, on what basis can you  state the last inequality?

Comment: $x^2+2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

substitute $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$, the expression $f(z)$ becomes $r\cos \theta \sin \theta e^{i\theta}$, continuity follows from boundedness of $\cos \theta \sin \theta e^{i\theta}$ as $r \to 0$